# I am having trouble with a error " local variable "num_of_rows" referenced before assignment" when I add a sql insert statement

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

First, I know this is a common topic on this board, but I still wanted to post because I could not find out the answer reading other posts. I have a function that inserts data into a SQL database to store and query hikes in National Parks.

It pulls data from comboboxes and entryboxes to get the data to the SQL statement. All of that is working fine, but I run into a problem midway through my insert steps. Please let me outline the steps.

1. Pull a primary key via SQL from the National Park (obtained through
   a combobox via a dictionary in the pyhton code).
2. Insert a new hike into the hike_tbl ( 5 values, a new primary key is
   generated automatically).
3. Get the primary key of the hike that was inserted.
4. Add the park primary key and hike primary key to the correct relationship table.
5. Add the hike primary key and difficulty primary key to a relationship table.
6. Add the hike primary key and route primary key to a relationship table.

Up to #4 it works fine. When I try to add another insertion statement (step 5 and/or 6), it gives me the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num_of_rows' referenced before assignment
```

This is a variable defined at the top of the code that should not be local, so I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated. Here is my relevent code.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import pymysql


# variables
rows = None
num_of_rows = None
blank_textboxes_tab_four = True
# ========= some database functions===========

def query_database(con, sql, values):
    try:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, values)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        num_of_rows = cursor.rowcount

    except pymysql.InternalError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.OperationalError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.ProgrammingError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.DataError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.IntegrityError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.NotSupportedError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        return num_of_rows, rows


# ======= add new hike tab 4========

def insert_into_database():
    try:
        con = open_database()
        # entry fields and comboboxes
        e_park = selected_park_e.get()
        e_hname = hike_name_e.get()
        e_length = length_miles_e.get()
        e_elev = elevation_ft_e.get()
        e_diff = selected_diff_e.get()
        e_nearcity = nearest_city_e.get()
        e_geoloc = geo_loc_e.get()
        e_route = selected_route_e.get()
        #print(e_park, e_hname, e_length, e_elev, e_diff, e_nearcity,e_geoloc, e_route)

    except Exception:
        messagebox.showinfo("Database connection error")
        exit()

    # Step 1: Get the Primary key of the national park
    # we need it for the hike/park rel table later
    try:
        sql = "SELECT park_id FROM park_tbl where park_name = %s"
        vals = (e_park)
        num_of_rows, rows = query_database(con, sql, vals)
    except DatabaseError:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error querying the database")

    park_PK = rows[0][0]
    print("park primary key", park_PK)

    # Step 2: insert a new tuple into the hike table
    try:
        sql = "INSERT INTO `hike_tbl` (hike_name, length_miles, elevation_gain_feet, " \
              "nearest_city, geo_location)  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        vals = (e_hname, e_length, e_elev, e_nearcity, e_geoloc)
        print(e_hname, e_length, e_elev, e_nearcity, e_geoloc)
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, vals)
        con.commit()
        print("inserted tuple")
    except pymysql.InternalError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.OperationalError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.ProgrammingError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.DataError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.IntegrityError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.NotSupportedError as e:
        raise DatabaseError

    #Step 3: now we need to get the new PK of this latest hike
    # we can get it like this
    new_hike_PK = cursor.lastrowid
    print("PK of new hike:", new_hike_PK)

    # Step 4: now we need to insert a tuple into `park-hike_rtbl` with the 2 Pks.
    try:
        sql = "INSERT `park-hike_rtbl` (park_id, hike_id) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        vals = (park_PK, new_hike_PK)
        #cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, vals)
        con.commit()

    except pymysql.InternalError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.OperationalError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.ProgrammingError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.DataError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.IntegrityError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.NotSupportedError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        con.close()

# Step 5: now we need to get the difficulty PK and insert a tuple into `hike_difficulty_rtbl` with the 2 Pks.
    try:
        sql = "SELECT difficulty_id FROM difficulty_tbl where difficulty_name = %s "

        vals = (e_diff)
        num_of_rows, rows = query_database(con, sql, vals)
    except DatabaseError:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error querying the database")

    difficulty_PK = rows[0][0]
    print("difficulty primary key", difficulty_PK)


    try:
        sql = "INSERT `hike-difficulty_rtbl` (hike_id, difficulty_id) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        vals = (new_hike_PK, difficulty_PK)
        #cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, vals)
        con.commit()

    except pymysql.InternalError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.OperationalError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.ProgrammingError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.DataError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.IntegrityError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.NotSupportedError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        con.close()

'''
# Step 6: now we need to get the route PK and insert a tuple into `hike_route_rtbl` with the 2 Pks.
    try:
        sql = "SELECT route_id FROM route_tbl where route_name = %s"
        vals = (e_route)
        num_of_rows, rows = query_database(con, sql, vals)
    except DatabaseError:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error querying the database")

    route_PK = rows[0][0]
    print("difficulty primary key", route_PK)

    try:
        sql = "INSERT `hike-route_rtbl` (hike_id, route_id) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        vals = (new_hike_PK, route_PK)
        #cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, vals)
        con.commit()

    except pymysql.InternalError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.OperationalError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.ProgrammingError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.DataError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.IntegrityError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    except pymysql.NotSupportedError as e:
        raise DatabaseError
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        con.close()
'''
def add_new_record():
    global blank_textboxes_tab_four
    blank_textbox_count = 0

    if hike_name_e.get() == "":
        blank_textbox_count = blank_textbox_count + 1

    if length_miles_e.get() == "":
        blank_textbox_count = blank_textbox_count + 1

    if elevation_ft_e.get() == "":
        blank_textbox_count = blank_textbox_count + 1

    if nearest_city_e.get() == "":
        blank_textbox_count = blank_textbox_count + 1

    if geo_loc_e.get() == "":
        blank_textbox_count = blank_textbox_count + 1

    if blank_textbox_count > 0:
        blank_textboxes_tab_four = False

        messagebox.showinfo("Database Error", "Blank Text boxes")
    else:
        try:
            insert_into_database()
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showinfo("Database Error", e)
            raise Exception

        messagebox.showinfo("Database", "Record Added to Database")
```

Comment: If a variable is at left side of an assignment anywhere in a function it is considered local to this function. If you don't want this, declare it as "global" at the beginning of this function (see the Python docs about the keyword "global").

Comment: The error is on the line `return num_of_rows, rows` inside `query_database()` because when there is error before the line `num_of_rows = cursor.rowcount`, `num_of_rows` is undefined when executing the return statement.

Comment: @ MichaelButscher HI, thank you for your comment. I don't think that is the problem for two reasons. 1. it did not make a difference when i assigned it as global, and also it worked for the first few insert statements.

Comment: @hiker Try adding `global num_of_rows` to the start of `query_database` and `insert_into_database` as Michael Butscher suggested

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you, can you say more specifically where the problem might be? would the error be coming from the SQL query to get the primary key or the insert itself? I would think it more likely the insert statement because the query is very simple.

Comment: I think that you have closed the `con` and `cursor` at step 4 may cause error when trying to query the database using closed connection and cursor.

Comment: Hi @TheLizzard I tried that, but it didn't make make a difference.

Comment: HI @acw1668  YES! that was exactly it! I forgot to remove that as I added more onto it.

Comment: HI @acw1668   Such a deceiving error code. If you want to post this as the answer I will be pleased to accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

question was answered: It was a simple error of not moving my close statement down after I added a new insert statement, but the error was very misleading, so this may be useful for someone else having this problem.

I think that you have closed the con and cursor at step 4 may cause error when trying to query the database using closed connection and cursor. – acw1668